# How would one use stubs for unit testing solidity code?

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing, mocha, unittesting

*Given* some contract `A`, that depends on another contract `B`, what would be the best way to unit test functions from `A` without inadvertently testing code from `B`.

Normally, we could use [stubs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174.aspx) to return data that is the same every time, but this is cumbersome to do manually with even a moderate amount of code (generate, compile, and deploy the stub).

Is there a framework or library out there yet that has this sort of functionality built in?

Also would be happy to provide a code example if the description above is too abstract; just comment.

#### I'm using:

- mochajs with chai assertions
- truffle for a testing framework
- ethereumjs-testrpc for test network

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stub contract. Deploying it in the test using truffle is not cumbersome. You can do it like so:

```
token1 = await Token.new()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done in the past is create a separate 'Stub' contract. So if you want to stub contract `B`, you create another contract `BStub` that inherits from `B` and override its methods to return some mock values instead. Then you initialise your `A` contract with a dependency on `BStub` instead of `B`. This has some drawbacks (like unavailability of `private` functions of `B`), but it can work well. Not sure if there are better ways to do this using a library or something, but this can be a good workaround.